# How to get notifications when status check of Pull Request passed or failed?

Tags: github

I started using https://github.com/manosim/gitify and I miss one thing: I don't get notifications when status check of Pull Request passed or failed. What's the easiest way to set it up? We don't use for project Github Actions/Workflows stuff.

Comment: Have you read their FAQs: https://github.com/manosim/gitify#faq

Comment: @astrochun Yes, I did. If you can see part about status checks let me know where to find it. I get other notifications normally.

Answer (score -2):

I have not used `gitify`. Based on what I read, I suspect that these notifications are still set at the GitHub settings level. Essentially if GitHub triggers a notification for your account/organization, that is captured from `gitify`. Take a look at the notification menu page: https://github.com/settings/notifications

You can adjust your GitHub Actions notifications. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure these notifications are triggered by Github and firstly I should see them https://github.com/notifications tab, but question is how to achieve it?

Comment: You can set it in the link I provided. Try that first.

Comment: Note also that at the lower left of the notification tabs are the settings.

Comment: I've already tried all of options there. I've been there earlier before asking for help.

Comment: OK, you should really clarify then because your OP does not specify what you have tried.

Comment: There was no single option about status check notifications.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by status checks notifications here. You had asked for pass/fail. There's an option for web notifications.